# Does Apache POI implement RTD from Excel?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, rtd

I'm using Apache POI to read and write MS Excel files that contain Excel's RTD (real time data) formula in some of the sheet's cells. When evaluating a cell, I call:

`cell.setCellFormula( (String) field);`

Field is the RTD formula that I'm calling. This throws the error `"org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedException"` when I attempt to evaluate the cell:

`FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();`
`evaluator.evaluate(cell);`

I suspect that Apache simply hasn't implemented RTD. However, I need to be able to constantly update this cell in Excel, which requires evaluating the RTD formula.

Is there some way to implement the RTD function from my end or is there another version of Apache (or some other Excel-parser) out there with this implementation?

Comment: "I suspect that Apache simply hasn't implemented RTD." Correct. [What functions are supported?](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html#What+functions+are+supported?). If you are able implementing the functionality of `RTD` using `Java` code, you can add the `RTD` function to `apache poi` as a user defined function as described in [User Defined Functions](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/user-defined-functions.html).

Comment: @AxelRichter thank you! I've successfully implemented a new function in `apache poi`, but just need to write the `RTD` functionality to it. I can't seem to find the `VBA` code anywhere for `RTD` so that I can translate it to java. Do you know of any sort of repository that contains Excel `VBA` code and may have `RTD`'s?

Comment: `RTD` is not written in `VBA` but is part of  `Microsoft Excel` which is closed source. So no, I do not know how it is implemented exactly.